# how to reuse old xampp mysql database and tables then old password need

Tags: mysql, xampp

My os formatted .i install new os .and install old  xampp files  in d drive.

how to reuse old mysql database tables after new intallations.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information. Did you make a dump of the database in SQL format? Is it the same mysql version? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you  made a backup  of your database then restore it to your current installation as

```
mysql -u root -p NameOfDatabase < saved-database.sql
```

or if you prefer to do that over web interface you can do that with help of

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

where you need to create first database with the same name it was previously and upload backup

[image: ![pma](http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/phpmyadmin/import/how-to-use-phpmyadmin-to-import-a-database.gif)]